# Sharing data between cucumber scenarios using guice

Tags: dependency-injection, cucumber, guice

I have this scenario where a data is been set and I want to use that data across different scenarios. I would like to do it using guice

```
Scenario: set data
Given user with data <sharedData>
Then user set sharedData

Scenario: get and verify data
Given user gets <sharedData>
Then user verify sharedData
```

I like to use this sharedData in all other scenarios. I was not able to fine a clear example with this arrangement using guice

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to not define the data in the scenario. Instead give the date a name and refer to it in the scenario. Then each of your steps can use this name to refer to the data, you can write a method in your step definitions to define the data, and you can use this method to provide the data in other step definitions to do comparisons, fill in forms etc.

Comment: My scenario 1 would fill in a huge form with about 50 fields and my scenario 2..n would have to access data in scenario to validate this form. I am using pico container for injecting dependencies. When ever my test comes on to scenario 2 my data object is setting to null.

Comment: So think about WHAT happens when this form is filled, and WHY its important for someone to fill this form, then write your scenario in those terms. A scenario should never talk about filling in a field (thats to much detail). Your technical problem about sharing data between scenarios should probably be dealt with in a separate question, (its very dependent on your platform).

Answer (score 0):

You can share this common data in an object injected by Guice. This object would be updated by the step that is triggered by `user with data <sharedData>`

Your problem is then transformed into how you share state between steps using Guice. I just released a [blog post](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/08/16/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-guice) describing one solution.

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas. I see its pretty neat to share state across steps. Is there a way to do it with picocontainer. Im using cucumber - picocontainer in my project.

Comment: Yes, picocontainer is supported. I wrote a blog post about it in April, http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer

Comment: But the share object is getting initialized for every scenario. How to keep the object for all the scenario's

Comment: Keeping objects for all scenarios would allow data to leak from one scenario to another. This is never desired. Scenarios must be independent and possible to run in isolation. If they are leaking state, you introduce dependencies between the scenarios. That is a dangerous and painful path to walk.

Comment: The solution for introducing pain and dependencies between scenarios is to store state in global variables. That is, public, static variables used randomly in the code base.